# Extract html value coming from endpoint in javascript / ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I came across one unusual scenario in reactJS where the endpoint is sending an object.
And one of the keys has value as stringified HTML.

The result of the endpoint is:

```
{
 "contact_columns": [
  {
    "label": "Don't have a policy yet?",
    "contactType": "URL",
    "value": "https://broker.bolttech.vn/",
    "subtextNode": {
      "childMarkdownRemark": {
        "html": "<p>Don't have a policy yet?</p>"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

I want the value "Don't have a policy yet?" from this endpoint.
Since it is inside a para tag so how to extract it and put it into a variable.

Please suggest how to do it?

Regards,
Arjun Sah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you got desired value use `replace` method to remove `<p>` and `</p>` tag from string.

```
const response = {
 "contact_columns": [
  {
    "label": "Don't have a policy yet?",
    "contactType": "URL",
    "value": "https://broker.bolttech.vn/",
    "subtextNode": {
      "childMarkdownRemark": {
        "html": "<p>Don't have a policy yet?</p>"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

Try to access like below

```
var htmlString = response.contact_columns[0].subtextNode.childMarkdownRemark.html.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const htmlString = '<h1>Hello World! ';

const App = () => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the working code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dangerouslysetinnerhtml-forked-ntt5c?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Solution**

If you will just have one level of HTML you can use something like this and any tag there will be removed.

```
response.contact_columns[0].subtextNode.childMarkdownRemark.html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')
```

---

**Dangerous Solution:**

```js
const a = document.createElement("div");
a.innerHTML = response.contact_columns[0].subtextNode.childMarkdownRemark.html;

console.log(a.innerText)
// "Don't have a policy yet?"
```

That way you can get the text ignoring if it is a p tag or another tag.

Try to avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and createElement because of XSS. Just use if you trust the input (don't trust users tho).